# How can I get the Data Array from my viewmodel in my fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm

Hello i'm in a pinch getting my  data for my Recyclerview in my Fragment. I have an API in my service that i call in my Viewmodel  but i don't understand how to link my viewmodel and my fragment (and setup the observer). For testing purpose we at first enter a predetermined array in the recyclerview but now we need to put the api request result in it.

so here is my fragment it has a adapter for the data

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment(), OnItemClickListener {
    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var viewAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<*>
    private lateinit var viewManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager
    private val viewModel: HomeViewModel by viewModels()


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)

        //Viewmodel  binding
        viewModel.listGenre.observe(viewLifecycleOwner){
            getMyData()
            Log.d("From OncreateView", viewModel.listGenre.value.toString())
        }


        // Set up the RecyclerView with a grid layout to display folders in 2 columns
        viewManager = GridLayoutManager(context, 2)
        viewAdapter = WebtoonsFoldersListAdapter(getMyData(), this, R.layout.item_webtoon_folder)
        recyclerView = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.fragmentHome_itemsList).apply {
            setHasFixedSize(true)
            layoutManager = viewManager
            adapter = viewAdapter
        }

        return view
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val floatingCreationButton: FloatingActionButton = view.findViewById(R.id.fragmentHome_newFolderButton)

        floatingCreationButton.setOnClickListener(fun(_: View) {
            // Create an AlertDialog builder
            val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this.context)
            builder.setTitle("Quel est le nom du dossier ?")

            // Set up the input field
            val input = EditText(this.context)
            input.inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT
            builder.setView(input)

            // Set up the buttons
            builder.setPositiveButton("Créer") { _, _ ->
                val folderTitle = input.text.toString()
                // Handle the folder title here
            }

            builder.setNegativeButton("Annuler") { dialog, _ -> dialog.cancel() }

            // Show the AlertDialog
            builder.show()

            // Set the focus on the input field
            input.requestFocus()
        })
    }

    // Give folders name to view
    fun getMyData(): Array<WebtoonFolder> {

        return arrayOf(
            WebtoonFolder("Skill","1"),
            WebtoonFolder("Scaling","2"),
            WebtoonFolder("TEST","3"),
            WebtoonFolder("21563","4"),
            WebtoonFolder("Mora","5"),
            WebtoonFolder("Mora1","6"),
            WebtoonFolder("Mora2","7"),
            WebtoonFolder("Mora3","8"),
            WebtoonFolder("Mora4","9"),
            WebtoonFolder("Mora5","10"))
    }

    // Change page when click on a folder
    override fun onItemClick(folderPos: Int) {
        println("Clicked on $folderPos")

        val mainActivity = (activity as? BaseActivity)
        mainActivity?.changeFragment(WebtoonFolderDetailsFragment(folderPos))
        mainActivity?.changeTitle(getMyData()[folderPos].getTitle())
    }

    override fun onItemDraw(holder: WebtoonsRecyclerViewHolder, position: Int, item: Any) {
        val webtoonFolder = item as WebtoonFolder
        holder.view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.itemFolder_title).text = webtoonFolder.getTitle()
    }
}
```

here is my viewmodel that i try to link it have an Array of Webtoonsfolder

```
class HomeViewModel : ViewModel() {

    //initialise la fonction API qui va etre demander et la passe dans notre Viewmodel  une page -> un viewmodel
    init {
        ApiRequest()
    }

    // The internal MutableLiveData that stores the status of the most recent request
    private val _status = MutableLiveData<String>()

    // The external immutable LiveData for the request status
    val status: LiveData<String> = _status

    private val  _listGenre =MutableLiveData<Array<WebtoonFolder>>()
    val  listGenre: LiveData<Array<WebtoonFolder>> =_listGenre



    private fun ApiRequest() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                val genresResult =
                    WebtoonOriginalsApi.retrofitService.getGenresList(Langage.fr).message.result.genreList
                for (i in 0..genresResult.count - 1) {
                    val temp = WebtoonFolder(genresResult.genres[i].name,genresResult.genres[i].code)
                    _listGenre.value?.set(i,temp)
                }

                
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                _status.value = "Failure: ${e.message}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my adapter class

```
class WebtoonsFoldersListAdapter(
    private val webtoonsFoldersList: Array<WebtoonFolder>, private val listener: OnItemClickListener, private val itemsLayoutId: Int
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<WebtoonsRecyclerViewHolder>() {

    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(
        parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int
    ): WebtoonsRecyclerViewHolder {
        return WebtoonsRecyclerViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(itemsLayoutId, parent, false), listener)
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: WebtoonsRecyclerViewHolder, position: Int) {
        listener.onItemDraw(holder, position, webtoonsFoldersList[position])
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener { listener.onItemClick(position) }
    }

    // Return the size of the dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    override fun getItemCount() = webtoonsFoldersList.size
}
```

so i tried multiple things from youtube and the net but none seems to work and i don't understand how android studio tutorial on viewmodel  can be applied here.

sorry if my english is poor it's not my mother language

Comment: Please, read this carefully, it helped me a lot. https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture/recommendations#viewmodel

Comment: This also will help. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel

Answer (score 0):

As you're using live data variables, this is how you need to fetch the data from ViewModel.

```
viewModel.listGenre.observe(viewLifecycleOwner){ items ->
            if(items.isNotEmpty()){
                // load the data to recyclerview.
            }
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

Your recicler view need a list to be builded, so if you don't update it, it'll never show properly.

#### First:

- If the list might be updated, you need store a list that could be updated on recycler view, you can achieve this approach creating a variable into the recicler instead pass it by params, that will store this list.

#### Second:

- You need a method into the recycler to update the list and notify that it has changed.

E.g:

```
class WebtoonsFoldersListAdapter(
    onItemClicked: (itemId: Int) -> Unit,
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<WebtoonsRecyclerViewHolder>() {

    private var webtoonsFoldersList: Array<WebtoonFolder>
   // code...

   fun updatWebtoons(webtoons: Array<WebtoonFolder>)
  {
    webtoonsFoldersList += webtoons
    notifyDataetChanged()
  }
}
```

And in your HomeFragment:

```
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        //Viewmodel  binding
        viewModel.listGenre.observe(viewLifecycleOwner){ webtoons ->
            
            recyclerview.updatWebtoons(webtoon)
        }
    }
```

Comment: This could work but it's not the correct way to procede. ViewModel should be independent from adapters. You should update the list in the activity / fragment and then notify the recyclerview that the list has changed.

Comment: From ViewModels documentation (best practices): Do not use ViewModels in reusable pieces of UI. You should use ViewModels in:

Screen-level composables,
Activities/Fragments in Views,
Destinations or graphs when using Jetpack Navigation.

Comment: The code shared wasn't about jetpack compose, further, I can't see any dependency on viewmodel related to the adapter, could you explain? therefore, I just given an a list based on api calls, how you think is the better way to proceed?

Comment: ViewModel should be independent from the Adapter. Please, carefully read this https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture/recommendations#viewmodel and this https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel. Activities and Fragment should be responsible for their ViewModels. I said compose since the documentation speaks also about compose. ViewModels also should not be in resusable pieces of UI, like RecyclerViews.